# Python add string to array but whenever theres a blank space make a new element?

Tags: python

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import cv2
import pytesseract
# Take picture
im = ImageGrab.grab()
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(730, 180, 970, 400))
# Show picture
im.show()
# Save picture
im.save('C:\\Users\\eddwik26\\Desktop\\phack\\screenshot.png')

# AI that reads string from picture
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
img = cv2.imread(r'C:\\Users\\eddwik26\\Desktop\\phack\\screenshot.png')
textFromImage = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
formatedText = textFromImage.replace("\n\n", "  ")
print(formatedText)
print("\n")

# Formatter
```

I need to know how to automatically add every new word after the dual blank space to a new element in an array
for example the image scanner returns the following text as a string
text example `output = apple banana orange`
I need to convert this to an array or similar so the array will store each fruit like this `array[0] = apple` `array[1] = banana` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are expecting?

```py
text = "apple banana orange"
array = text.split()
for i in range(len(array)):
    print(array[i])
```

**Output**

```
apple
banana
orange
```